# react-images: image in carousel not centred

Tags: css, next.js

I would like to center the selected image instead of having it showing on the left hand side.

See image of behaviour:
[image]

I'm using the packages from the sandbox below in Next.js 11 with TailwindCSS 2.2.4:
https://codesandbox.io/s/5vn3lvz2n4

Dependencies:
"react-images": "^1.2.0-beta.7",
"react-photo-gallery": "^8.0.0"

I'm having a hard time targeting the CSS class, but I narrowed down to:
class="react-images__view react-images__view--isModal css-1qrom1v css-1ycyyax" using the browser dev tool in Safari.

Below is my PhotoLibrary file:

```js
import React, { useState, useCallback } from "react";
import Gallery from "react-photo-gallery";
import Carousel, { Modal, ModalGateway } from "react-images";
import { photos } from "../data/photoData";

export default function PhotoLibrary() {
  const [currentImage, setCurrentImage] = useState(0);
  const [viewerIsOpen, setViewerIsOpen] = useState(false);

  const openLightbox = useCallback((event, { photo, index }) => {
    setCurrentImage(index);
    setViewerIsOpen(true);
  }, []);

  const closeLightbox = () => {
    setCurrentImage(0);
    setViewerIsOpen(false);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Gallery photos={photos} onClick={openLightbox} />
      <ModalGateway>
        {viewerIsOpen ? (
          <Modal onClose={closeLightbox}>
            <Carousel
              currentIndex={currentImage}
              views={photos.map((x) => ({
                ...x,
                srcset: x.srcSet,
                caption: x.title,
              }))}
            />
          </Modal>
        ) : null}
      </ModalGateway>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Has anyone played around with the carousel in Next.js and able to see what I'm doing wrong? If you have a better solution I'm open to that too.

Comment: It appears that you have already fixed it. On the given sandbox I am getting this output: https://i.imgur.com/IbwaBuE.png -- the image is perfectly centered.

Comment: No, it doesn't work in my local Next.js project. That's the weird part, but I somehow think it is related to tailwindcss, but I don't know. :-)

Comment: Have you checked the output on [production](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/cli#production)? `next build` `next start` Also can you check on some other browser (than Safari) on your local setup?

Comment: I tested it on production build with Safari, Google Chrome and Firefox Developer Edition. 

Same behaviour all around. :)

Comment: Having the same problem with NextJS.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following CSS to your globals.css file.

```
.react-images__view-image--isModal {
 display: inline-block;
 left: 50%
}
```